# gcloud beta pubsub - Invalid choice 'pubsub'

Tags: gcloud

I'm following this guide - https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-console

I am at the bottom where it says to enter `gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions pull MySub`.

I definitely installed beta:

```
$gcloud components install beta

All components are up to date.
```

However, I keep getting this error: `ERROR: (gcloud.beta) Invalid choice: 'pubsub'.`

I saw the documentation - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/pubsub/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What Cloud SDK version do you have? Run `gcloud version`

Comment: Google Cloud SDK 115.0.0

alpha 2016.01.12
app-engine-python 1.9.38
beta 2016.01.12
bq 2.0.24
bq-nix 2.0.24
core 2016.06.21
core-nix 2016.03.28
gcloud 
gsutil 4.19
gsutil-nix 4.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcloud pubsub` was only available in alpha until version 118.0.0. Please update your tooling and try again.